# Angular - Bind Dropdown or select to API (database)

Tags: angular, rest

I was on a project with Angular and a backend.

If I enter a list in the ts file:

```
this.towns = [{
       code: '1',
       label: 'Paris'
   },
   {
       code: '0',
       label: 'Vancouver'
   }
 ];
```

I can display them in my html but not if I try to connect to a db:

```
<select  class="selectpicker dropdown mt-4 ml-3" id="town">
   <option *ngFor="let town of towns" [value]="town.id">{{town.name}}</option>
</select>
```

In my ts file, I tried:

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
 
  form: FormGroup;
  towns: { id: number, name: string }[];
 
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }
 
  towns: Town[];
  apiUrl = 'https://localhost:8000/api/';
 
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      town: new FormControl()
    });
    this.getTown();
  }
 
  onClickTown(): Observable<any> {
    console.log(this.form)
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + 'towns')
  }
 
  getTown() {
    this.http.get<any[]>(this.apiUrl + 'towns')
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.towns = data;
        console.log(data)
      });
  }
 
  postData() {
    console.log("data");
    this.http.post<any[]>(this.apiUrl, {}).
      subscribe(
        (data: any[]) => {
          // console.log(data);
        }
      )
  }
```

Did I forget a step?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you declare the towns property two times?! `towns: { id: number, name: string }[];` and `towns: Town[];`

Comment: @ArmenStepanyan, getData?I have a getTown and in my console it shows:  [link](https://postimg.cc/Tp46kKFd) like this.

Comment: @RamiAssi, that might be because I tried many things and forgot to take the wrong ones down. Thanks. I missed it

Answer (score 2):

This is because changes are not detected. You can try reinitializing the towns array so that Angular detects changes.

```js
getTown() {
  this.http.get<any[]>(this.apiUrl + 'towns')
    .subscribe(data => {
      /* reinitialize the towns array */
      this.towns = [];
      /****/
      this.towns = data;
      console.log(data)
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution and didn't get progress but noticed a new error "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays." that apparently could be solved if I put "| async" in my ngFor but didn't.

Comment: This means that the returned data is apparently not an array. The problem is definitely not in the answer. Please include the output of `console.log(data)` in your question

Comment: The returned data shown in your screenshot is not an array. It is an object. Make sure that you are calling the right API method or you might need to provide extra parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below.

I've used the `async` pipe to iterate. (Notice you should return Observable for that)
I've also used the `ngValue` attribute to bind to the form

HTML

```
<select formControlName="town">
  <option *ngFor="let town of towns | async" [ngValue]="town">{{town.name}}</option>
</select>
```

TS interface

```
exprot interface Town{
  id:number;
  name:string;
}
```

TS Component

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  towns:Observable<Town[]>;
  apiUrl:string = 'https://localhost:8000/api/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {        
    this.towns = this.http.get<Town[]>(this.apiUrl + 'towns');        
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      town: new FormControl()
    });
  }
```

Comment: thanks. I tried the |async and changed on my getTown function:

Answer (score 0):

I changed my getTown function to solve it and so my html:

```
  getTown() {
    this.townsObs = this.http.get<any[]>(this.apiUrl + 'towns').subscribe(data => {
        this.towns = data['hydra:member'];
        console.log(data['hydra:member'])
      });
  }
```

Thanks to you all